# Angular directive that can clone itself using $compile - Illegal use of transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a "chart widget" directive with a clone button that will clone the chart and append it right after the original.

The directive looks like this:

```
app.directive("chartWidget", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A", 
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'chart-widget-template',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.clone = function () {
                var clone = $compile("chart-widget-template")($scope);
                element.after(clone);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

With the template as follows:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="chart-widget-template">
    <section class="widget chart-widget">
        <i ng-click="clone()" class="widget-clone-handle"></i>
        <div class="body no-margin">
            <div ng-transclude></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</script>
```

And usage as follows:

```
 <div data-chart-widget>
    <div data-some-specific-chart-directive></div>
 </div>
```

At first I tested the cloning to work without transclusion succesfully. However, once I add the transclusion in the mix, cloning it produces this error:

> Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in
>   the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found.
>   Element:

The angular docs for $compile state that the transcludeFn parameter to $compile is depracated (not that I know how it works anyways), so how would I accomplish this?

To clarify, I want the original transclusion aka:

```
<div data-some-specific-chart-directive></div>
```

to be included in each clone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Here is a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ktEOsswQx3FyJ2pISqey?p=preview

You need to use the 5th argument of the linking function aka $transclude:

```
app.directive("chartWidget", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A", 
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'chart-widget-template',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
            $scope.clone = function () {
                $transclude(function(clone){
                  element.after(clone);  
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The transclude function that is passed to the compile function is deperecated

See this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/90f87072e83234ae366cfeb3c281503c31dad738

---

#### Another plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0MJtWpXqLzOMuuA3DX0r?p=preview

- use `$templateCache.get` to load the template
- pass a `transcludeFn` as the second argument to `$compile`

**Directive:**

```
app.directive("chartWidget", function ($compile, $templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: "A", 
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'chart-widget-template',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
            var template = $templateCache.get('chart-widget-template');
            scope.clone = function () {
                var clone = $compile(template,$transclude)(scope);
                element.after(clone);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works although it only clones the transcluded content without its template. As I'm sure you know, you've removed my call to $compile (I guess to simplify it) but I'm confused how to get back my previous bevahior of cloning the entire template not just the transclusion

Comment: @parliament I added what you asked :)

Comment: It works and does answer the question so I'll accept it, thank you for your effort. I am however, still having an issue where the scope is shared between each clone, so changed to one affect all clones. Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LWSew0Mmyr7qyUfqUV6I?p=preview. The intended bevaior is to clone the scope but keep seperate references so that each can change individually. I tried angular.copy(scope, {}) however that's explicitly not supported. I can start a new question if you'd like :)

Comment: @parliament here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rrkiEzzTvMw7fjkk77em?p=preview

Comment: Ilan I've reproduced your code successfully several times in plunkrs, fiddles, even in a new project. It works everywhere except in my project. For some reason "this" in "this.isCollapsed" keeps refering to the same scope for different clones =\ do you have any idea why ive been bumping my head on this for hours

Comment: The directive should have `scope:true`

Comment: Indeed i have that set. Only way it works in my project is with scope: true and $compile(...)(scope.$new()). But EVEN THEN, collapsing the original still causes the clones to collapse UNTIL I collapse one of the clones ONLY THEN does it "break off" and create its own scope. Does that give any clues?

Comment: There is also this way with isolate scope that also works: http://plnkr.co/edit/87di3sKqmN8yH4ShLB8a?p=preview

Still passing same scope in my solution :\

Comment: Ilan i figured out what was the problem with my code and I've been able to replicate the issue. However, the solution is not obvious to me, I've posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/22134335/1267778